# using json in mvc 5 controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
$(function ()
{
    function getValueUsingClass() {
        /* declare an checkbox array */
        var chkArray = [];

        /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
        $(".chk:checked").each(function () {
            chkArray.push($(this).val());
        });

        /* we join the array separated by the comma */
        var selected = chkArray.join(",") + ",";

        /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
        if (selected.length > 1)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/StateController/MyResult",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                type: "POST",
                data: {"randstuff": chkArray},
                success: function () {
                    // do things upon success
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error!");
                }
            });
        }
         else
         {
            alert("Please check at least one of the checkbox");
         }        
    }

    $("#Charter").click(function () {
        getValueUsingClass();
    });
});
```

My Javascript code. 
This gets me the Id of the checked boxes, i want to send this data to my controller, so that i can use it to select those particular values from my database. This is my first time using Jquery and Ajax, i have managed to get this far but i'm still quite lost.

```
public JsonResult MyResult(int[] randstuff)
        {
            return Json();
        }
```

I know i'm meant to have a method like this to receive the data from the script file, but i'm not really sure how to go about that. I want to create an array from the received Json data, which i can then use to loop through my database and select only values who have matching Ids that are in the array.

Comment: Does this code work? Are you receiving the array of checkbox values in the `MyResult` method? Or, is this question really "Now I have my values, how do I use them to update my database?"

Comment: i guess you're right actually.... I have my values, my problem is passing them into my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a bit of extra fluff in your code, and that it can be cleaned up. Let's take a look at `getValueUsingClass` (see my comments in the code itself):

```
function getValueUsingClass() {
    // no need for looping and building the array manually, we've got .map() for that
    var chkArray = $('.chk:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get(); // turn into basic array

    // check if the chkArray has any elements, don't build a string
    if (chkArray.length > 1) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("MyResult", "StateController")', // let MVC build URL for you
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // type sending
            dataType: "json", // type receiving
            // traditional: true, // not necessary
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'randstuff': chkArray }), // serialization
        }).done(function () { // use jQuery promises
            // do things upon success
        }).fail(function () { // use jQuery promises
            alert("Error!");
        });
    } else {
        alert("Please check at least one of the checkbox");
    }        
}
```

Now, MVC should be able to deserialize your JSON request into the `int[]` array in your controller method, as long as it allows POSTing via the presence of an `HttpPostAttribute`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyResult(int[] randstuff)
{
    return Json();
}
```

Comment: so youre saying i can just do something like " var selectedlist = randstuff "  to get the array and then make the return statement like this "return Json(selectedlist);"

Comment: @lagfvu: You could `return Json(randstuff);` -- .NET will serialize `randstuff` back into a JSON array. If you don't need to know anything more about the array in the UI, you don't have to return it back. Use the values to update your database and `return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and in `done`: `.done(function(result) { if (result.success === true) { alert('success!'); })`

Comment: @Cory all i need is the array containing the values so i can use them to select items from my database. i don't need to make any changes to my database.